# How to Persist XMLGregorianCalendar?

Tags: java, xml, schema, persistence, w3c

Is there a recommendation on how to persist Java's XMLGregorianCalendar object to a relational database? Or better yet, is there an API/library to do so? I'd prefer it if I didn't have to know before-hand what Datatype it represents (e.g. xsd:date, xsd:dateTime, xsd:gDay, etc.), just that it can universally handle all. It would be nice if relational database operators could be used when querying it, as well. Otherwise, I'd probably store it as a serialized string.

Comment: [hyperjaxb3](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/HJ3/Home) is a project that attempts to bridge JAXB and JPA. Based on the analysis done to implement persistence of JAXB using JPA ([JAXB vs JPA](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/HJ3/JAXB+vs.+JPA)), it seems the issue is complex enough that it's unlikely there would be a recommended way for persisting XMLGregorianCalendar.